# Google Maps API - Read place details from JSON response

Tags: c#, json, google-places-api

Ok, I'm finally getting the response I was looking for from Google Places API. The response is separated by each address field. but now, I just want to retrieve these fields.

For example, how can I retrieve the street number (90) from the json bellow?

My code until now:

```
string url = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" +
                  placeId + "&language=pt-BR&key=AIzaSyDYQ6IIsukjFEQ5VEaxL2VgLf8kRLSXuBM";

var result = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

dynamic detalhes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

Here's part of the response:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Casa A",
            "short_name" : "Casa A",
            "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "90",
            "short_name" : "90",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Rua Carlos",
            "short_name" : "R. Carlos",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Campo Belo",
            "short_name" : "Campo Belo",
            "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "São Paulo",
            "short_name" : "São Paulo",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "São Paulo",
            "short_name" : "SP",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "13450-050",
            "short_name" : "13450-050",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create models for your JSON:

```
public class Response
{
    public ResponseResult Result{ get; set; }
}
public class ResponseResult
{
    public ResponseResultAddress[] Address_Components{ get; set; }
}

public class ResponseResultAddress
{
    public string Long_Name { get; set; }
    public string Short_Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Types { get; set; }
}


var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
var street = data.Result.Address_Components.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Long_name == "90" && item.Types.Contains("street_number"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a tool such as [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create a class model out of the given json. This will result in something like this:

```
public class AddressComponent
{
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize the given json string into an object of type `RootObject` using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

To query the deserialized `data` object for the `street_number` part you can make use of LINQ:

```
var streetNo = data.result.address_components.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.types.Contains("street_number"))?.long_name;
```